# Shifting LIs down using CSS

Tags: html, css

This is the html content I want to add.
These are 4 verticals of my firm and they have individual clients and I want the logo of these clients yo appear in the same box moving downwards shifting the remaining text downward and the logo gallery running downward.

```
  <div class="box1">
     <div class="box1_bot">
        <div class="box1_top">
           <div class="pad" >
              <h2>CLIENTS</h2>

                 <ul>
                     <li><a href="#home">Consultants4manpower</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#news">Corporate Training</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#contact">English and PD Training</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#about">Career Counselling</a></li>
                </ul>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please visit the [help] to see how to ask. Also please first look [here](https://www.google.come/search?q=vertical%20slideshow%20css)

Comment: Please, add your jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script>

function show_logo_home(){
var loc = document.getElementById("logo");
var linknews = document.getElementById("news");
var linkcontact = document.getElementById("contact");
var linkabout = document.getElementById("about");
loc.style.visibility="visible";
loc.style.marginTop="-227";
linknews.style.marginTop="150";
}
</script> 
<style>
#logo {
background-color: #F00;
height: 150px;
width: 150px;
margin-left: 30px;
position: absolute;
visibility:hidden;}
</style>
</head>
 <body>
 <div class="box1">
 <div class="box1_bot">
    <div class="box1_top">
       <div class="pad" >
          <h2>CLIENTS</h2>

             <ul>
              <li ><a href="#home" onclick="show_logo_home()"id="home">Consultants4manpower</a></li>
                 <li id="news"><a href="#news" onclick="show_logo_news()"id="news">Corporate Training</a></li>
                 <li id="contact"><a href="#contact" onclick="show_logo_contact()"id="contact">English and PD Training</a></li>
                 <li id="about"><a href="#about" onclick="show_logo_about()"id="about">Career Counselling</a></li>
            </ul>
       </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

<div id="logo"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: sir the link to page where i want you to look into is :http://shubhamenterprises.education/about.html

Comment: Sir,In the client division suppose if i click on consultants4manpower then i want that the remaining three name shift downward and the logo of the client related to c4m comes scrolling downward as if we do it by marque tag.please help me out.

Comment: the Client div get resized automatically

Comment: apply same function for all with some changes with position or u can create a side popup with <li>

Comment: and what if i want 4 logos all togehther coming down??

Comment: i mean to say when i click on Consultants4manpower then 4 diffrent logos come down scrolling that is there are 4 different clients associated with each of them.

Comment: you should make a popup for 4 logos when user click on any option a pop comes up then display all info of client with popup you can add more info for associated clients

Comment: i have posted some javascript and css transition use that pop code

Comment: if any problem comes up.will get in touch with you again.

Comment: by the way sir i jst want to add logos.4 logos after each section.i dont want any pop up ,it should come scrooling down in same div where i have four categories mentioned.

Comment: the logos will have backlinks redirecting to their individual websites.

Comment: consider the logos as images i say.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div id="demo"></div>
 <button id="btn"onclick="popup()">click me</button>
   <style>

    #demo {
-webkit-transition: all 2s ease 0s;
-o-transition: all 2s ease 0s;
-moz-transition: all 2s ease 0s;
transition: all 2s ease 0s;
height: 0px;
width: 0px;
   }

   </style>
  <script>
    function popup(){
    document.getElementById('demo').style.cssText='height:500px;  width:500px;background-color:red;position:absolute;'
    document.getElementById('demo').style.marginLeft=250;
    document.getElementById('demo').style.marginTop=50;
   }
 </script>
```

Comment: You need to explain what you are doing in your answers. SO is not a place one comes to get someone to write their markup for them.

Comment: Mr. Rob i am a beginner.the peice of code i have written i have sent.I think SO is a place where  can get further assistance.

Comment: Still if SO have any problem.I will work on it more from my side and then will get back to SO.

Comment: Comments:@Vikas Kandari                                                                                          sir this is the renewed piece of code.[link]http://shubhamenterprises.education/about.html                                                            What i want is the logos should appear only when i click on the respesctive vertical say:consultant4manpower.In same box shifting the remaining three verticals name downwards.

Comment: First Creat a Div for logo for client then use the code i have provided,Idea of the code is when user click on the link(LI) then a function will run and set,s the div element,s position below the <li> then and aslo sets the position of rest links so when user click's on link div will visible and other will shift according to div position, i have provided a sample code above so use it for every Link(li)